# Pull To Refresh Jump in iOS

Tags: ios, scrollview, uirefreshcontrol

When I slowly pull down to refresh, I see the UIActivityIndicator circle slowly get more complete before it starts the refresh.  Just before the circle is complete and the refresh actually triggers, the content jumps/jerks down and then the circle starts spinning.  I only notice this when I pull down slowly.

I'm using the pull to refresh inside a scroll view called mainSV

```
    self.refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.mainSV addSubview:self.refresh];
```

Why does this jump/jerk happen?

Comment: Are you using storyboards? What is your target iOS?

Comment: I have a main story board. The scroll view is in a xib.  I just noticed this isn't a problem in iOS 6, it only jumps in iOS 7.

Comment: `refresh` changed between iOS 6 & 7. I'll provide an answer...

Comment: actually my mistake, `refresh` implementation changed between Xcode 4.5.2 and Xcode 5+

Answer (score 8):

It's probably a bug in iOS. Your setup is correct, and I see the same thing in my app.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the jump/jerk is due to a "double" action.

There was a change to `refresh` implementation following the release of Xcode 5.

As such, the requirement to set a target action as described in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) is no longer necessary.

As you are using a Storyboard, in your Interface Builder / Storyboard file, select your storyboard scene (table view controller).

In the attributes inspector, under the subheading **Table View Controller**, select the item "Refreshing" and change the setting from "Disabled" to "Enabled".

[image: Attribute Inspector for Table View Controller]

Delete or comment out the three lines of code you have included in your question. (When it was required, i.e. prior to Xcode 5, I placed this code in my `viewDidLoad` TVC lifecycle method.)

If not automatically inserted into your code, then add this as either a public or private `IBAction`...

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender;
```

and wire to your scene / table view controller to the **Sent Event** "Value Changed".

[image: Visual representation of outlet connection]

Ensure your refresh action is properly configured...

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    //  Refresh code for your TVC

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Note that no property is required to be set for `refreshControl` - I suspect there is a trigger to automatically synthesise this when you choose the setting Refreshing [Enabled] in your TVC attributes in the storyboard.

If you need to call the refresh from in your code, use this line...

```
[self refresh:self.refreshControl];
```

Comment: If I understand it right - this works only for a subclass of `UITableViewController`? But not for `UITableView` inside of `UIViewController`?

Comment: I still get a jump/jerk when implementing this way :(

Comment: @oyatek per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/) you are correct, the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller. Not sure where the second option is mentioned in the question though?

Comment: @lostintranslation you may need to add some more code to your question... for example to explain the code that is running when you trigger the refresh?

Comment: Also another question... Does the behaviour repeat when you pull down at normally?

Comment: Actually only happens the first pull. I have text set. And text is very close to spinner initially as I pull down. As I get to the bottom the jump happens when the text correctly spaces itself from the spinner. Even time I pull after the first time it seems to behave correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see the rest of your code (or at least the scrolling + refreshing methods) to diagnose the problem.

Here's our tutorial for implementing custom pull to refresh controls in objective-c and swift.  If you follow this tutorial you shouldn't see any jumping or jerking.

http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Old questions but if someone still has this issue and you are using NavigationController just make your NavigationBar "Translucent".

[image]

Using non translucent NavigationBar causes the tableview to jump slightly when UIControlEventValueChanged is fired for some reason.

XCode 10.1