# UIRefreshControl - collectionView jumps when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a problem with `UIRefreshControl`. When I scroll down the `collectionView` the content of the `collectionView` jumps a little bit up.

GIF here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL1z5.jpg

I have already seen some question about this exact problem, however, I haven't been able to find an answer that would work for me. (for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769967/pull-to-refresh-jump-in-ios))

I have a `UICollectionViewController` inside another `UIViewCotroller` as a subview.

I have implemented `UIRefreshControl` like this:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
    self.collectionView?.refreshControl = self.refreshControl                      
} else{
    self.collectionView?.insertSubview(self.refreshControl, at: 0)
}

self.collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshControlChanged), for: .valueChanged)
refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
```

Also, I want my collectionView to refresh data after the user stops dragging.

```
@objc func refreshControlChanged(){
    if !(self.collectionView?.isDragging)!{
        nextRecommended()
    }
}


override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if refreshControl.isRefreshing{
        nextRecommended()
    }
}
```

And inside `nextRecommended()`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @dahiya_boy actually, it is a vertical `UICollectionView`

Comment: can you please highlight your issue. I unable to get your issue? Either you have issue in the refreshController or your screen is bit up?? share your screen images also to understand your issue in better way.

Comment: @dahiya_boy If you look closer at the GIF, the collectionViewCell jumps a bit up. You can see it when I am scrolling slowly.

Comment: Can you test the same by keeping the refresh loader for 5 sec. Bcz as im seeing it is working properly, as you leave the collectionView, CollectionView first moves to the initial position(below refreshView) and when refresh loader finishes then it moves up(at top). In case of slow scrolling it takes time and loader is loading and in case of fast, the collectionView is directly moved to the top position.

Comment: @dahiya_boy The problem is that it jumps a bit up during scrolling down.

Comment: Just check first, sometimes it may differs with the test cases.

Comment: @dahiya_boy the problem is not in keeping the refreshControl loading longer. The problem is with the jump of the cell while scrolling.

Comment: Just some ideas for you to play around with (these changes are not meant as solutions, but to diagnose the problem): 1. comment out reloadData() in  nextRecommended; 2. set alwaysBounceVertical to false in your callbacks; 3. remove dispatching to the main queue (your callbacks already execute on the main thread)